# How create a generic Func delegate

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, func

I have this method

```
    public static T F<T>(T arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }
```

and I want to create a Func delegate to F. I try this

```
public Func<T, T> FuncF = F;
```

but it's not syntactically correct. How I can do that.

Comment: Seems fine to me https://dotnetfiddle.net/JRjFxU

Comment: @dcastro You've added something that is not in the original question, which is why it works.

Comment: @DStanley I assumed the enclosing class was generic :/ I assumed too much

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only classes and methods can be generic in and of themselves.  A field that uses generic parameters must be within a generic class context:

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public static T F(T arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }

    public Func<T, T> FuncF = F;
}
```

Or if the type parameter for `F` should not be connected to `FuncF`, then just use a different name for one of the parameters:

```
public class Test<T>
{
    public static U F<U>(U arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }

    public Func<T, T> FuncF = F;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only (re)expose generics from a generic class, or in a generic method. Otherwise, you will need to provide definite types for `T` (e.g. for a local variable or as a field or property in a non-generic class). Examples:

```
// I.e. Re-expose by wrapping your Func in a static class:
public static class MyFuncs
{
    public static T F<T>(T arg)
    {
        return arg;
    }
}

public class Generics<T>
{
    // Use it as a field
    private Func<T, T> f = MyFuncs.F;

    // Or getter func
    public Func<T, T> FuncF()
    {
        return MyFuncs.F;
    }
}

// Re-expose generic via Generic Method
public class GenericMethod
{
    public Func<T, T> FuncF<T>()
    {
        return MyFuncs.F;
    }
}


// i.e. Consume the generic and do not re-expose it
public class SpecificClass
{
    public Foo FuncF(Foo f)
    {
        return MyFuncs.F<Foo>(f); // <Foo> is optional - compiler can infer
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`F<int>` is a method which would be assignable to a `Func<int, int>` variable.

`F<double>` is a different method which would be assignable to a `Func<double, double>` variable.

But you cannot have a generic variables. C# just doesn't work like that.

The closest thing to generic variables is a field of a generic class:

```
static class DelegateContainer<T>
{
  public static Func<T, T> FuncF = F;
}
```