# Can I write this lambda with IEnumerable<T> rather than IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to write this lambda in a more generic way? It works fine, but seems too specifically typed; the content of the `IEnumerable`s are not touched, but should be preserved in the return type.

```
static readonly Func<
    (IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>),
    (IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>),
    (IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<string>)
> JoinListTuples = (a, b) =>
    (a.Item1.Concat(b.Item1),
        b.Item2.Concat(b.Item2));
```

I was thinking of something like this, but it doesn't compile:

```
static readonly Func<
    (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>),
    (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>),
    (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>)
> JoinListTuples = (a, b) =>
    (a.Item1.Concat(b.Item1),
        b.Item2.Concat(b.Item2));
```

Comment: The lambda is fine.  The declaration of the field you initialize with the lambda is a problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to define a generic lambda in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404993/is-it-possible-to-define-a-generic-lambda-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How create a generic Func delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26758915/how-create-a-generic-func-delegate)

Comment: Please **do not** edit your questions to show/contain answers,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types can be generic, methods can be generic, but fields cannot be generic.

A workaround when you really need to have this generically as a delegate type is to make it a field of a generic class:

```
public static class HelperClass<T, U> {
    public static readonly Func<
        (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>),
        (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>),
        (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>)
    > JoinListTuples = (a, b) =>
        (a.Item1.Concat(b.Item1),
            b.Item2.Concat(b.Item2));
}
```

But for most purposes, it would suffice to just turn it into a method instead.
Perhaps something like this:

```
static (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>) JoinListTuples<T, U>(
    (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>) a,
    (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>) b)
{
    return (a.Item1.Concat(b.Item1),
        b.Item2.Concat(b.Item2));
}
```

Comment: ;) ill upvote because you did a better job of explaining

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will help you

However, something like this maybe

```
public class SomeHelper<T,U>
{

    public static readonly Func<
        (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>),
        (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>),
        (IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<U>)> 
            JoinListTuples = (a, b) => 
               (a.Item1.Concat(b.Item1),b.Item2.Concat(b.Item2));

}
```

Note, untested and not in front of VS

Comment: Heh, you beat me to it. Yes, that compiles exactly the way you have it now.